# PHP preg_replace string text

Tags: php, regex, string, replace, preg-replace

I am trying to replace every instance of:

```
{{anythinghere::anythingthere}}
```

in a string.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: and what do you want to replace them with?

Comment: Assuming the rest are literal characters, define *anything*. Also answer **Spudley**'s question.

Comment: replace what with what? Give me example string and the desired result

Answer (score 3):

As you didn't specify what you want to replace it with:

```
preg_replace("/{{([^:}]+)::([^:}]+)}}/", "First_param: $1, Second_param: $2", $target_string);
```

This would return `First_param: anythinghere, Second_param: anythingthere`.